# Linear interpolation function isn't giving desired results

Tags: interpolation, procedural-programming

```
xyvalues = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}}
EQ = Append[
  EQ, {(xyvalues[[2, 2]] - xyvalues[[1, 2]])/(
   xyvalues[[2, 1]] - xyvalues[[1, 1]])  , 0 < x < 1}]

EQ = {}
For[ i = 1, i < 4, i++;
  EQ = Append[
    EQ, {(xyvalues[[i + 1, 2]] - xyvalues[[i, 2]])/(
       xyvalues[[i + 1, 1]] - 
        xyvalues[[i, 1]]) *(x - xyvalues[[i - 1, 1]] ) + 
      xyvalues[[i - 1, 2]], 
     xyvalues[[i - 1, 1]] < x < xyvalues[[i, 1]]}]
  ];
Print[EQ]
```

Result from printing EQ that matters to me:
`{{3 x,0<x<1},{1+5 (-1+x),1<x<2},{4+7 (-2+x),2<x<3}}`

First thing i can see is wrong, is that Instead of the first thing being `3x, 0<x<1` when I'm expecting `x, 0<x<1`.  I The first few lines of code are written with the intention of checking to make sure I'd get 1 and it gives me a slope of 1 so I don't know where the hell 3 is coming from.

To clarify what my code is doing in the forloop
I have my dataset xyvalues which is just a parabola for convenience but the program is meant to work with ANY dataset.

I take the point 0,0 and make a straight line from it to 1,1.
The point is to plot a piecewise function from point to point.  In my for loop I wrote out the way to get the equation of each line using point-slope form, that is
$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ or $y=m(x-x_1)+y_1$
M from 0,0 to 1,1 should be 1 but I get three and it seems to be happening in the for loop. Hope this makes sense. its 5am and I screwed up on this assignment by doing polynomial interpolation by accident.

When it comes down to it I just want to know why the slopes for each piecewise part arent what they are meant to be which can be seen with 3x not just being x.

Comment: Look at your input: Should not "EQ = {}" be at the beginning? Otherwise it does not make sense. With this fixed, I get: {{1,0<x<1},{3 x,0<x<1},{1+5 (-1+x),1<x<2},{4+7 (-2+x),2<x<3}}

Comment: EQ is at the begining of the loop to initialize it. All the stuff prior to the loop was me testing to make sure the stuff in the loop works. Ill give it a shot though

Comment: This code is going to be killer slow, in case you're trying to use it for large-scale stuff. For that, it's better to use `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder->1]` to force linear interpolation.

Comment: The general advice found in this forum is to drop using `For` and use `Table` or `Do`.

Comment: @imarben007 I recommend to use `Map` , `Apply`, `Nest`,`NestList` etc. instead of use `For`,`Do` or `Table`

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this.  My for loop needed a comma instead of ; after i++. This more or less fixes the problems occuring.